# Did Alphonse Daudet exchange anti-Semitic correspondence with Richard Wagner?

Tags: french-language, alphonse-daudet, richard-wagner

The French novelist Alphonse Daudet (1840–1897) is best known for works such as *Lettres de mon moulin* ("Letters from My Windmill"), the *Aventures prodigieuses de Tartarin de Tarascon* and his three-act play *L'Arlésienne*. According to the [Wikipedia article about the author](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Alphonse_Daudet&oldid=1058321132#Political_and_social_views,_controversy_and_legacy),

> Daudet also exchanged anti-Semitic correspondence with Richard Wagner.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

The statement has no source. The [French Wikipedia article about the author](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Alphonse_Daudet&oldid=188573050#Antis%C3%A9mitisme) has a section on his anti-Semitism but does not mention Wagner. The [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphonse_Daudet) mentions that Daudet at some point gave money to [Édouard Drumont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Drumont), who "initiated the Antisemitic League of France in 1889", but does not mention Wagner.

Is there any evidence about correspondence between Daudet and Wagner that contains anti-Semitic statements?